# Resize FormSheet does not get affected

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am displayin my viewcontroller in the formsheet, but the default size is more than I need, therefore, I am trying to resize to match my requirement, but nothing has changing.

```
var vc = new WSViewController();
vc.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet;
vc.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve;
PresentViewController(vc, true, () => {
    vc.View.Superview.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    vc.View.Superview.Center = View.Center;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I set `PreferredContentSize` in the `ViewDidLoad()` method, then it works. Make sure you deployment target is iOS8.0+

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
   base.ViewDidLoad ();
   TableView.Source = new TableSource ();
   this.PreferredContentSize = new CGSize(620, 220);
}
```